# Code is not displaying first result

Tags: php, html, mysqli

About this code:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT subcategories.subcat_name, subsubcategories.subsubcat_name FROM subcategories INNER JOIN subsubcategories ON subcategories.subcat_ID=subsubcategories.subcat_ID WHERE subsubcategories.subcat_ID = 1");
$subcat_name = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<div class="grid_5 alpha omega" id="titlescontent"><p class="titlebar"><?php echo $subcat_name['subcat_name'];?></p></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="grid_5 alpha omega" id="content"><ul class="subcat">
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?><li><?php echo $row['subsubcat_name'];?></li><?php
}
?>
</ul></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

For some reason it starts displaying the subsubcat_name from the 2nd result and not the first one which I also want to be displayed. Any idea how come and what I need to change in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I see you need that first one for the title? In that case, try this alternate approach:

Replace your `while` loop with:

```
$row = $subcat_name;
do {
    echo "<li>".$row['subsubcat_name']."</li>";
} while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
```

What does this change? It basically means the loop body will run for your initial row, then for the rest.

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you have extra mysqli_fetch_array call